# How to prevent Windows Explorer from reusing the existing Excel instances?

Tags: excel, windows-explorer, ole-automation

I have a number of different programs where I create Excel instances and control them via OLE automation. In some cases the user can also work with these instances through Excel UI (which may involve opening other workbooks), in others they remain hidden.
Problems arise when the user double-clicks an Excel file in Windows Explorer to work with it for some other, unrelated purpose. Explorer would grab any running instance and open the file in it, which may interfere with a running macro, or the instance may be currently hidden and thus unusable via UI.
Is there a way to create an Excel instance in a "special" way to prevent it from being seen by Explorer?